# I have a previous invention (software / framework) that I plan to use on my new job. What happens to my copyright if I improve it during the job?

Tags: licensing, legal, copyright

I have filled that standard form where you list your previous inventions before starting your new job so the employer is legally aware you have the copyright over them. But if I want to use this invention (software code / framework) in my new job, would they have any copyright claims on it if for example I change / improve something on my code while working for them?

I have heard something like a shared ownership. Something like: you would own what was done before and employer would own any improvements you did on it while employed. That kind of sucks and take away any incentive you would have to do improvements on your product since *once improved, the improvement is gone*. :(

Has anyone gone through this situation before and could share some ideas so I can protect my code?

Comment: Have you considered open-sourcing your previous invention? How about selling it to your new company on an as-is basis for a nominal fee? Then you could just re-sell it to them any time you make improvements.

Comment: @Baqueta I have other things that I open source, but this particular project is not in my best interest to open source it. I plan to sell it later to other companies and/or use it again in other assignments I may have and/or other jobs.

Comment: @Baqueta - Making the project open source does nothing about future work being controlled by a restrictive IP agreement.  The company must release any claim to John's work in order for him to continue working on it.

Comment: Have you considered selling them the current version of the whole thing and transfer ownership to them for an adequate price? If you insist to keep ownership, your new employer could insist that you are completely responsible for the maintenance that software, 365 x 24h per year.

Comment: @GlenH7: Wouldn't one of the copyleft licenses force the work to remain in the public domain? JohnPristine: Fair enough!

Comment: @Baqueta - only for the existing work.  Any new work is potentially subject to the IP agreement.

Comment: @Baqueta - sorry, more clearly:  a copyleft license or any other license will only protect the existing work. Any new work is potentially subject to the IP agreement, which is really what this question concerns.  Incidentally, the employer doesn't have a claim to the existing work because it was generated before the terms of the IP agreement took effect.

Comment: @GlenH7 But any improvements would also have to come under the copyleft license since they would constitute 'derirative work'. Agreed that we are off on a tangent from the thrust of the original question though, so let's leave it be. :)

Comment: Its best you don't use a single line of code from a project you plan on selling to other companies.  If your employeer is interested in your product they can PAY you for it.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on what is in your employment contract.

I had to ask to have a specific clause added to my contract that allows me to work on open-source projects in my spare time. The original contract claimed all copyrighted material that I produced during the period of my employment, whether I was at work or not.

If it is not explicitly stated in your contract, local labour laws would likely apply, and you'd need to consult a lawyer. You might need to anyway - there are certain rights that you simply can't sign away, no matter what a contract says.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, you want to retain ownership of that software.

If this is so, simply do not sign a contract that takes it away from you.

The normal case, however, is, that what you produce during your working hours is owned by your employer. Your renumeration should be compensation for that.

Maybe you can reach an agreement, where the hours you work on imporvement of that invention are not counted (and paid) as working hours. Instead, your employer agrees to buy (a license for) the improved version for approximately the same amount as you woulod make in those hours.

Comment: One solution may be that I will ONLY make improvements during my off-ours. But the company would probably not agree to have something dependent on a close-sourced product/framework. I don't mind showing them the code and they can do modifications if they want/need in the future. But I would like to keep ownership in the product and in the code like you said.

Comment: @JohnPristine it really depends on how badly they need it. Look, they probably depend on close-sourced Windows. OTOH, if you give them a source code license, it is not closed source anymore.

Comment: "They can do modifications if they want/need" = *you* doing the modifications for them. and if they make modifications they own those modifications unless you can convince them to officially push them "upstream"

Comment: Additionally, if you make updates/improvements in your work version of the application, then try to add those same updates to your personal version, it leads to them potentially being able to bring legal action against you for infringing on "their property".

Comment: @BBlake So if you find a bug you can never fix that bug in your system?

Comment: Only a lawyer familiar with software copyright law can really answer that for sure, but your best bet is to avoid the situation entirely and leave work and personal code entirely separate.  At many companies it is policy that you are not allowed to take code home or export it outside the company for any reason or to bring in outside code that has not been obtained via a purchased licence contract with the owner.  Many won't even allow common "public domain" or opensource code.  They just don't want to be left open to potential lawsuits either way.

Comment: Alternatively, why don't you grant them a license to use the software in exchange for the right to keep copyright over your own changes? They get the software, and you still own the updates. It should be win-win. Unless they want to sell your software to other people, in which case, I'd sell a license for them to do that, and negotiate for a cut of the profit.

Comment: Even if one does not sign a contract, in many places in the world, anything written while in the office is considered "work product" now in some locations companies ATTEMPT to gain ownership of ANY work product but in most cases where thats been challenged the company lost.  The point of this comment is in attempt to warn the author of mixing work and his own business together.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple problem.  You need to make sure there is an intersection between your interests and your employer's interests in this matter.

Does your new employer even care about using your code?  Do they want it?  If so, then add it to your agreement that any modifications to that code:

1. you retain copyright to
2. they retain full, unlimited, permanent, transferable, sublicensable, etc... licence to use, reuse, etc...

If they are too big to do that, then simply don't take your software there.

Answer (score -5):

Maybe the best thing to do is to open source it first, with maybe an MIT license. Then, use it  at your new job. The new employer wouldn't be able to claim ownership of an open source project that was created\released before your employment began.

Shared ownership sounds messy. I can't imagine that scenario being best for you, but I can see the company getting the better end of that arrangement.

Comment: Open source for this particular project is not on my best interest. I have other things open source it.

Comment: This is a bad, if not terrible, suggestion.  Placing the project under an MIT license will protect the _existing_ code, but does nothing for future development.  Under a very restrictive IP agreement, all copyright for future work belongs to the employer.  Your suggestion puts the asker in conflict with his work agreement if he makes new contributions to the project.  He cannot legally contribute something he does not own.

Comment: OP is not interested in taking ownership over what his company does to modify the project. He's interested in keeping control over what he's already built. Edit: Read some of OP's other responses; I'd just declare the work as pre-existing and not use it with your new employer.

Comment: @KamauMalone - Not using it is the best suggestion I have seen. Why complicate matters...the author wants to sell his product he should keep his personal business seperate from his work with this company.  He should not even work on ANYTHING connected to his product to be honest.

Comment: It is just infrastructure code that I want to use in other places.